# Comprehensive comparison: Applying for US Green card under EB1-A or EB1-B, when have both options

Tags: usa, greencard

Can someone provide a comprehensive comparison of pros and cons of filing for US Green card under category EB1-A vs EB1-B assuming you have eligibility of filling under both the categories, i.e.,:

1. Your employer is ready to sponsor EB1-B and,
2. Attorneys recommendation is that your profile is strong enough for EB1-A (so it will anyways qualify for EB1-B).

Please feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Why not do both?

Comment: @littleadv I guess the cost will be an issue. If it's just one of them the company will cover entire thing and you won't have to pay anything on you.

Answer (score 1):

Pros:

EB-1A - You're not dependent on any employer and can sponsor yourself.

EB-1B - You save a little money by having your employer bear most of the costs. I don't know how significant this is for you, but given the qualifications I'd assume not very much.

Cons:

EB-1A - Much higher bar, but if your attorney says you can satisfy it then probably not really a concern.

EB-1B - You're dependent on a job offer, if your employer decides not to employ you anymore the application disappears.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This is the general comparison between EB-1A and EB-1B. However, my question was for the scenario when the employer is ready to pay for either category and attorneys think either category is fine then which one should one pick? Further, another thing I want to ask does it gives some sort of advantage to the employer if it's EB-1A?

Comment: You want someone to make a decision for you?

Comment: Who is asking that? I am asking that other than the obvious and standard differences mentioned in your response are there some hidden side of it. You may not be able to think any or there may not be any. But that's what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Also, EB1 category has 40K visas each year. But are they split equally into the, A, B and C sub categories? If yes, then this could also be a factor as one may want to choose a subcategory, A or B, which is expected to have least number of applications. These are the kind of things I am more interested in coming into discussion.

Comment: @ChorSipahi You mentioned you had an attorney, why aren't you asking them these questions?

Comment: What is this forum for? I thought a forum for discussion and knowledge exchange. Why is this an issue if I want to discuss an issue in general form such that answers are available for all and in more open form. If you don't want to/can't answer then it's fine. But why an open and generic discussion is a problem?

Comment: @ChorSipahi it's not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A forum.

Comment: Okay. Then let's stop discussing the other ways I can get answers, like asking my attorney. If you have more to add to your answer, I would appreciate your insights. Else, maybe someone else will answer. @littleadv